# Cannot convert Hash to String?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to parse the JSON response from Wordnik's API. This is built with Sinatra. I keep getting the error "TypeError at /word" "can't convert Hash into String". Am I using the json parser incorrectly?

Here's my code:

```
get '/word' do
  resp = Wordnik.words.get_random_word(:hasDictionaryDef => 'true', :maxCorpusCount => 20, :minLength => 10)
  result = JSON.parse(resp)
  word = result.word
  return word.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are probably getting a hash. To convert it use `to_json`:

```
JSON.parse(resp.to_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not given what's the JSON response that you are parsing. But assuming it is something of the form

```
{
    "word":"my_word"
}
```

you need to do result["word"] to get the value after parsing the JSON response.

Comment: I switched `word = result.word` to `word = result["word"]` but I get the same error.